# How Powermock framework creates mock objects?

Tags: java, junit, mocking, junit4, powermock

I want to know the technique used behind the creation of mock objects by Powermock? I also want to now how the technique used in mock creation help us verify the behavior of the mock? If anybody can explain with an example it would be more helpful.

Answer (score 4):

See http://www.jayway.com/2009/05/17/mocking-static-methods-in-java-system-classes/ for details. Here it is described how Powermock works under the hood.

Comment: I checked now. It works. maybe it was temporary or your network is not ok. Please try again later

Comment: Link only answers are not good.
You should inlcude some quotes and/or an abbreviation of the article.